# Junit exceptions on separate thread with Coverage

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, junit

Using Android Studio, when testing a piece of code that uses threads, I found a great solution to verify an exception is thrown. Using `UncaughtExceptionHandler` on the thread in test and `join()` to wait for this thread to finish.

It all works perfect on a normal test run and even on debug. The problem comes when running it with coverage the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is never called with the thrown exception and so the test fails as it's expecting to see an Exception.

One of the hypothesis I have is that the thread is run in a way that it doesn't throw unchecked exceptions (i.e. with a catch somewhere else) But I don't know how to validate this or solve the problem since I can't debug and run with coverage at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if android testing uses the same Junit api I'm used to in thick-client java, but I'd use the **ErrorCollector** TestRule to pull the off-threaded process exceptions back to the main test thread, and **ExpectedException** to verify I get the exception type, message, and/or cause that should result from execution.

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

public class ThreadExceptionTest {
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exEx = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void doThreadTestFail() throws Exception {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    throw new RuntimeException("drat");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    collector.addError(ex);
                }
            }
        };
        Thread th = new Thread(r);
        th.start();
        th.join();

    }

    @Test
    public void doThreadTestPass() throws Exception {
        exEx.expect(RuntimeException.class);
        exEx.expectMessage("drat");

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    throw new RuntimeException("drat");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    collector.addError(ex);
                }
            }
        };
        Thread th = new Thread(r);
        th.start();
        th.join();

    }
}
```